# Does this formula take constant value?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Now, $x_i, \xi, f \in R^n(i= 1, 2, \cdots , k)$, and
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^T\xi=f
\end{align}
holds.
If the above equation is solvable about $\xi$, the value of $f^T\xi$ doesn't depend on
 $\xi$ (that is, if $\xi_0$ and $\xi_1$ are solutions of above equations, $f^T\xi_1=f^T\xi_2$ holds)?

I think this instinct may be true, but can't prove this.

I tried to prove considering the operator $\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^T$ is similar to projection
operator, but this trial didn't succeed (if $||x_i||=1$, the consequence is self-evident).

I also tried to solve the following optimization problem, 
\begin{align}
\textrm{Minimize}&\ \ f^{T}\xi\\
\textrm{subject to}&\ \ \sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^T\xi=f   
\end{align}
, hoping that $f^T\xi$ is constant everywhere in the feasible region, but it didn't succeed.

Perhaps pseudo inverse matrix may be useful, though I have little knowledge about it.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'solvable about $\xi$'?

Comment: @Semiclassical It means that the equation about $\xi$ has some solution, but it may not be unique.